# How to detect a USB drive in Lynx OS?

Tags: unix

In Linux, when I insert a USB stick, the USB shows up in `/dev`, usually as `/dev/sdb` or something similar.

Right now I am trying to backup a computer running Lynx OS, when I insert a USB stick, nothing new is added to `/dev`. How do I locate this USB stick from the command line within lynxos?

I don't want to mount it, because I intend to use `dd` to clone the HDD onto the USB. However, I need to know where to point the output in `dd of=...`

Comment: do you see anything in dmsg?  `dmsg | grep usb`

Comment: dmesg/dmsg is not installed on this system.